# How do I perform a fuzzy query for each word in a sentence using Lucene / Hibernate Search?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to take a sentence with some potential spelling mistakes in it, for example: "I love yava, IDEA IntelliJ, JoyoScrapt, GWT, hypernate, Rolling and spring", and perform a fuzzy search that will match to Tags that I have indexed by Lucene, e.g. "hibernate" and "java".

I thought I had this working by generating a query string like the one below:

"I~0.5 love~0.5 yava,~0.5 IDEA~0.5 IntelliJ,~0.5 JoyoScrapt,~0.5 GWT,~0.5 hypernate,~0.5 Rolling~0.5 and~0.5 spring~0.5"

Unfortunately the behaviour is strange though. If the sentence was shorter then the misspelled words would match to the example tags that I gave. However, when the sentence becomes longer, then they no longer match.

Anyone know the proper way to accomplish what I am trying to do, i.e. a fuzzy logic match on a per word basis? I also tried building up a separate term query for each word and then adding them to a BooleanQuery but I didn't get any better results.

Answer (score 0):

Your query string looks a bit odd, with some "misplaced" ',', but that is maybe just a typo. Basically the idea of fuzzy search is right. I would, however, not use the 0.5 parameter. It is the default and deprecated in Lucene 4.

Can you give some more concrete example on what is strange with the result?

As an alternative approach you could build up a synonym list for your tags containing the most common misspelled versions for your tag. This way you don't need to rely on fuzzy searching. You index the synonyms along with the tags.

Comment: hi @hardy, the commas aren't misplaced. They are in the original sentence, I just replaced spaces with ~0.5. I'm not worried about the actual number (i.e. 0.5), I intend on using 0.7 anyway. My problem is regardless of the number used, the behaviour is weird.

Comment: Say for example I have a tag "java" and the sentence I search for is short e.g. "Love yava" then the misspelled word (yava) will match to tag "java". This is what I expect. However, if the sentence is longer like the one I gave in my original post and it also contains the misspelled word "yava" then the tag "java" is not returned as a result. If I am doing a fuzzy match on a per word basis, I would expect "yava" to match "java" regardless of what sentence it is in.